# Graphql create object with fragment

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I can query a graphql object like this

```
info {
  firstname
  lastname
  phone
  email
}
```

I want to create an object `contactInfo` so I can query `contactInfo` and put phone and email inside that.

```
info {
  firstname
  lastname
  ...contactInfo
}
```

```
fragment contactInfo on person {
  contactInfo: {
     phone
     email
  }
}
```

but this keeps giving me error, how can I use fragment to put phone and email inside `contactInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `person` definition and verify is written correctly.
Then you should put inside your fragment just the fields that are in that definition.

With the info provided I think that you should remove the `contacInfo` field, that name is alredy defined with the sentence `fragment contactInfo on person`

```
   fragment contactInfo on person {
      phone
      email
    }
```